# Search a part of a List<> based on the indext of a pattern match

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to define a LINQ response to this issue, I have a `List<List<string>>` and I need to compare the first line of the internal list and return that list based on the match:

```
List<List<string>> mainList = new List<List<string>>();
List<string>lines = new List<string>();
lines.Add("one");
lines.Add("two");
lines.Add("three");
mainList.Add(lines);
lines=new List<string>();
lines.Add("bus");
lines.Add("clock");
lines.Add("chicken");
mainList.Add(lines);
```

How do I use LINQ to return the entire list which contains `"bus"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to compare **any element** in the Sub List then do:

```
List<string> subList = mainList.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Contains("bus"));
```

If you only want to **compare first element** in the Sub List then do:

```
List<string> subList = mainList.FirstOrDefault(r => r.FirstOrDefault() == "bus");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this one:

```
var result = mainList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Contains("bus"));
```

The above query will search all the list contained in the `mainList` and it will return you the first List that contains the string "bus". If there wasn't such a list then you would have gotten a `null`.